# How to write bytes by byte and display it continuously

Tags: java

I have encrypted video file and while decrypting it i have defined Byte`byte[] input = new byte[1024];` size to written it in output file.
Here i want to write first 1024 bytes in output files while at same time if want to play that video file i can play that output file without waiting to whole file written like video streaming.

when first 1024 bytes written , video file will start playing till whole file will written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to setup your input stream and output stream depending on where you're getting the data and where you're saving/viewing it. Performance could also likely be improved with some buffering on the output. You should get the general idea.

```
public class DecryptionWotsit {
    private final BlockingDeque<Byte> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Byte>();
    private final InputStream in;
    private final OutputStream out;
    public DecryptionWotsit(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void go() {
        final Runnable decryptionTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    byte[] encrypted = new byte[1024];
                    byte[] decrypted = new byte[1024];
                    while (true) {
                        int encryptedBytes = in.read(encrypted);

                        // TODO: decrypt into decrypted, set decryptedBytes
                        int decryptedBytes = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < decryptedBytes; i++)
                            queue.addFirst(decrypted[i]);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // exception handling left for the reader
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        final Runnable playTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        out.write(queue.takeLast());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(decryptionTask);
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(playTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the writing in a separate thread.
Since writing to file is a lot slower than displaying video, expect the file-writing thread to be running long after you've quit watching the video. Unless (as I understand it) you intend to write *only* the first 1024 bytes to file.

If you intend to write the entire video to file, a single 1024 byte buffer will slow you down. You will either have to use a buffer that is a lot larger, or need a lot of these 1024-byte buffers. (I suppose the 1024 byte buffer size is a consequence of the decryption algorithm?)
Also, you may want to look at how much memory is available for the JVM, to make sure that you won't get an OutOfMemoryException halfway. You can use the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options to set the amount of memory available to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to write to a file, you also want to process is to open the file twice (or more times). In one thread you write to the file and update a counter to say how much you have written e.g. a `long` protected by a `synchronized` block.  In the reading thread(s) you can get this value and read up to that point, repeatedly until the writer has finished. A simple way to signal the write has finished is to set the size to Long.MAX_VALUE, causing the readers to read until the EOF.  To stop the readers busy waiting, you can have them wait() until the data written is greater than the amount read.

This approach always uses a fixed amount of memory e.g. 16 - 128K, regardless of how far behind the readers are from the writer.